# How can I solve the runtime error problem in hacker rank while the same code runs successfully in VScode?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner user=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
            String s1=user.nextLine();
            int x=user.nextInt();
            user.nextLine();
            String space =" ";
            for(j=0;j<=15-s1.length();j++){
                space =space+" ";
            }
            if(x<100){
                System.out.println("================================\n");
                String.valueOf(x);
                String new_x="0"+x;
                System.out.println(s1+space+new_x+"\n");
                System.out.println("================================\n");
            }
            else if(x<10){
                System.out.println("================================\n");
                String.valueOf(x);
                String new_x="00"+x;
                System.out.println(s1+space+new_x+"\n");
                System.out.println("================================\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("================================\n");
                System.out.println(s1+space+x+"\n");
                System.out.println("================================\n");
            }
        }
        user.close();
        }
}
```

The problem in hacker rank talked about writing strings and integers in input and making space between strings and integers.

Space + String must equal 15 index, and I put the link to the hacker rank question under the code.

This is Hacker rank link:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-output-formatting/problem?isFullScreen=true

I tried to solve a HackerRank question on their website using Java, and it ran successfully in VS Code.

However, when I attempted to run the same code on HackerRank, I encountered a runtime error.

When I deleted all the for loops in the code, it gave me the wrong answer, not a runtime error.

Comment: There are literally infinite possible Runtime Exceptions that can happen in java. So I'm afraid unless you can provide us with more information about what that Runtime Error is that is happening, the chances of anyone figuring out what is wrong are rather small.

Comment: Please [edit] the code and add the full stack trace of the exception. Please also highlight the line of code where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` - you should iterate **exactly 3 times**. The correct is `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`.
- Another big problem, you **shoule not close** the scanner `user.close();`. It is not an external resource, this is build-in java `System.in`. You close the scanner, i.e. you close this stream and anyone cannot use it anymore. But HackerRank framework you is afterwards.

**P.S.** By the way. Let me show you more elegant and efficient solution. You can use `String.format()` to build required string.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("================================");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String s1 = sc.next();
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(String.format("%-15s%03d", s1, x));
    }
    System.out.println("================================");
}
```

Comment: They are using _nextLine_ also, instead of _next_.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the format would be,

```java
System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
```

Output

```
================================
java           100
cpp            065
python         050
================================
```

The full list of *printf* format specifiers can be found on the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class *JavaDoc*.

If you're not familiar, the *[printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf)* syntax is mostly inherited from the *[C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))* *printf* format.

Here is a relevant excerpt from the *JavaDoc*.

> *"... Formatted printing for the Java language is heavily inspired by C's printf. Although the format strings are similar to C, some customizations have been made to accommodate the Java language and exploit some of its features. ..."*

It's very simple to use, a specifier is denoted by a `%`, followed by a letter.
An `s` represents a *String*, a `d` represents an integer value, and an `f` represents a floating-point value.
There are additional specifiers as well.

You can modify the specifier with width, padding, and justification attributes.

> *"... The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax: ..."*

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width]_[.precision]conversion
```

Although, to answer your question specifically, as to why it is erroring.

The error is an *[InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)*, which is caused by the following line.

```java
int x=user.nextInt();
```

This is because your preceding *Scanner* capture uses the *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* method, instead of the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* method.
In the original *HackerRank* example, they are using *next*.

```java
String s1=user.nextLine();
```

The difference between the two is that the *nextLine* method will return the entire line,

```
java 100
```

And, the *next* method will return just the token; in this case *"java"*.
The default delimiter is a white-space character.

*[Scanner (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)*.

> *"... A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods. ..."*

Thus, calling *nextInt* will attempt to return *"cpp"* as an *int*, which doesn't parse.

Subsequently, you are making another call to *nextLine* after this; which will cause it to error further.